# How to access a dictionary nested in another dictionary with dynamically generated keys?

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

So I have a function that looks something like this:

```
    def get_thing_dict(self):

    results = {}
    grand_total = 0.0

    # String looks like "a1,b,c1,d1,a2,b2,c2,d2" etc.
    new_string = self.get_string().split(',') 

    while new_string[:4]:

        # Get group of 4
        new_string_line = new_string[:4]

        # Split data
        location = new_string_line[0]
        description = new_string_line[1]
        price = new_string_line[2]
        qty = new_string_line[3]

        # Add parts to dictionary
        results[location] = {'description': description,
                               'price': price,
                               'qty': qty}

        # Calculate and update total
        line_total = float(price) * int(qty)
        grand_total += line_total

        # Remove used data
        new_string = new_string[4:]

    # Add total to dictionary
    results['total'] = grand_total

    return results
```

The dictionary will look something like: `{'a1': {'description': 'b1', 'price': 'c1', 'qty': 'd1'}, 'a2': {'description': 'b2', 'price': 'c2', 'qty': 'd2'}, 'total': 1.0,}.`

I need to then be able to iterate through the dictionary in flask to produce a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>b1</td><td>c1</td><td>d1</td>
        <td>.....................................</td>
        <td>.....................................</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1.0</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I can't figure out how to firstly only loop through the keys whose value is another dictionary without knowing they're keys, and secondly how to actually access the items within the nested dictionaries without knowing the key.

There may be a really obvious answer but I can't think how to word the question correctly to look it up elsewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
for key1, val1 in d.items():
    if isinstance(val1, dict):
        for key2, val2 in val1.items():
            # do what you need with inner dict key/vals here
    else:
        # do what you need with total key/val here
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems you need a table to store and access the data

```
  while new_string[:4]:
      # Get group of 4
      new_string_line = new_string[:4]

      # Split data
      location = new_string_line[0]
      description = new_string_line[1]
      price = new_string_line[2]
      qty = new_string_line[3]

      results.append([location, description, price, qty])

      # Remove used data
      new_string = new_string[4:]

  df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['location', 'description', 'price', 'qty'])

  # if you want  total number 
  total = (df.price * df.qty).sum()


  location description price qty
0       a1          b1    c1  d1
1       a2          b2    c2  d2
```

access data

```
df[df.location == 'a1']
  location description price qty
0       a1          b1    c1  d1
```